# wsgen: returning an abstract class

Tags: java, wsdl, xsd, wsgen

I wrote an abstract class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
public abstract class Parent
    {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "one")
    public String getOne() { return "one";}
    }
```

and two derived classes:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
@XmlRootElement(name="child1")
public class Child1 extends Parent
    {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "two")
    public String getTwo() { return "2";}
    }



import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
@XmlRootElement(name="child2")
public class Child2 extends Parent
    {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "three")
    public String getThree() { return "3";}
    }
```

and a @webservice:

```
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import javax.jws.*;
import java.util.*;

@WebService(serviceName="MyServerService", name="MyServer")
public class MyServer
    {
        private int count=0;
    @WebResult(name="test")
        @WebMethod
    public Parent getOne() { return ++count%2==0?new Child1():new Child2();}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Endpoint.publish(
            "http://localhost:8080/path",
            new MyServer());

        }
    }
```

When the code is generated using **wsgen**, the resulting XML schema only contains the definition for the abstract class **Parent** but not for **Child1** or **Child2**. Is there any way to tell wsgen to generate the definition for the two concrete classes ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding an annotation `@XmlSeeAlso` should do the trick:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({Child1.class, Child2.class})
public abstract class Parent {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "one")
    public String getOne() { 
       return "one";
    }
}
```

If you prefer not to make parent class aware of its subclasses you can put that annotation on the WS level as well:

```
@WebService(serviceName="MyServerService", name="MyServer")
@XmlSeeAlso({Child1.class, Child2.class})
public class MyServer {
    private int count=0;

    @WebResult(name="test")
    @WebMethod
    public Parent getOne() { 
        return ++count%2==0?new Child1():new Child2();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/path", new MyServer());
    }
}
```

Interesting information about this behavior you can find [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/using_type_substitution_with_web)